# CUDA 11.5 bandwidth test sample build fails with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: build, cuda, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to build bandwidth_test sample from CUDA 11.5 and it fails with:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
> 11.5.targets(785,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin\nvcc.exe"
> -gencode=arch=compute_35,code="sm_35,compute_35" -gencode=arch=compute_37,code="sm_37,compute_37" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code="sm_50,compute_50" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code="sm_52,compute_52" -gencode=arch=compute_60,code="sm_60,compute_60" -gencode=arch=compute_61,code="sm_61,compute_61" -gencode=arch=compute_70,code="sm_70,compute_70" -gencode=arch=compute_75,code="sm_75,compute_75" -gencode=arch=compute_80,code="sm_80,compute_80" -gencode=arch=compute_86,code="sm_86,compute_86" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu
> -I./ -I../../common/inc -I./ -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5/include" -I../../common/inc -I"C:\Program
> Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\include"  -G
> --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static --threads 0 -g  -DWIN32 -DWIN32 -D_MBCS -D_MBCS -Xcompiler
> "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Fdx64/Debug/vc142.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MTd " -o
> x64/Debug/bandwidthTest.cu.obj "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA
> Samples\v11.5\1_Utilities\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest.cu"" exited with
> code 1.

I looked everywhere but, I can't find the problem. Also there are no additional errors in the logs or I can't find any.

Does anybody knows why is this happening?

By the way the first sample deviceQuery can be build and I can execute it but I guess that one does not use nvcc.

Comment: Could you please show what exactly you're trying to build?

Comment: Turn the visual studio verbosity up (just google that) until the error from `nvcc` that is behind this: "exited with code 1." becomes visible.  This is likely a problem with your cuda install.

Answer (score 1):

You've got [error MSB3721](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-fix-error-msb3721/47471), which does not say anything on its own.

> MSB3721 is the VS way of saying “I ran nvcc, and it returned an error code.”
>
> Other than knowing that your compilation failed, it is completely
> useless for understanding why it failed.
>
> To understand why, it’s necessary to increase the verbosity of VS
> output so that it shows the actual invocation of nvcc and the actual
> error reported by nvcc (prior to VS reporting the MSB3721 error).
>
> If you google how to increase verbosity of VS output, you’ll be able
> to find articles explaining how.

Comment: When i turned on verbosity it says "The system cannot find the path specified." and i have this in the build command:
 "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\/include"

Note the backslash before include, this can't be right. How can i change this, if this is the problem?

Comment: @DuskoMurtovski check out `include` paths in the properties of your project, there must be a mistypo